# How to test in device while offline?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I am using Xcode 7.1. I have successfully managed to run/debug my app from Xcode 7.1 into an iOS 9 device. However that only works while the device is online. If it is offline I get an "Untrusted Developer" error message when I try to run the app. This is a problem since my app has some offline behavior that I need to test.

How can I test my app while the device is offline?

I have already trusted the profile in Settings > General > Profile.

[image]

I am not sure if I also need to verify the app. I tapped on Verify App several times. But nothing happens. The app stays in unverified state.

PS. I have not enrolled for any iOS Developer program.

Comment: Are you using the new ability to load apps to a device even if you do not have an iTunes connect developer account? Never seen this happening, maybe it's a limit Apple had imposed.

Comment: iMoses, I have not purchased any iOS Developer program. The ability to test using a device in this situation is new in Xcode 7.1.

Comment: I speculate that this is a limitation on free accounts, but you'd better wait for someone with a free account who could confirm or claim the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use you applications offline. In XCode 7 check your Preferences>Accounts and make sure that you are logged into you apple ID in XCode and your iOS Device.

You may need to verify the app while online the first time before running offline.